# German translation of the word "ample"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, translation-request, mathematical-german

I am looking for a German translation of the word "ample" as in "ample line bundle". The literal translation of the word is *reichlich* but I am not so sure whether the term *reichliches Geradenbündel* is actually being used. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know you would just use 'ample' in German as well, although technically it is not a German word.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~weissaue/vorlesungsskripte/AlgebraischeGeometrieXYVersion.pdf

Comment: I usually use Wikipedia to translate such things. In this case, the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ample_line_bundle doesn't have a German version, so I assume that there is no term for it in German (i.e. the English term is used). If there is a German version of a page, then I can get the name from there. Not always 100% perfect, but working often enough for my needs. :)

Comment: *Ein amples Geradenbündel* sounds extremely ugly to me. I don't know whether there is a standard translation but I would say *reichhaltiges Geradenbündel* (instead of reichliches).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. It seems that it is not unusual to keep the English term, although I concur that this sounds a bit silly.